# Get url from images stored in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, html-parsing

How can I fetch the URL from images stored in Parse?

I have made an app where I can store images into Parse (works fine).
But how do I retrieve the URL from the image stored in Parse so I can show it in a web browser by typing the URL?

Can I see the URL for the images stored in Parse anywhere?

I'm thinking something like this:

https://www.parse.com/apps/ClassName/collections#class/Photo/CzEgPXalzM

Comment: What Parse SDK are you using for your website (PHP, javascript,...)?

Comment: Im using Parse SDK version 1.7.5. The meening are, that when im sharing af picture, i want the link sent in the email or SMS message. The link are there, but the image stored in Parse are not showing

Comment: I meant for which platform: PHP, iOS, javascript, etc?

Comment: iOS. Using latest Xcode :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the url of the image from the `PFFile` object containing the image like this:

```
NSString *urlString = yourImageFileFromParse.url;
```

Comment: Yes, i have this line of code. But how can i fetch the URL line from Parse and paste it into a webbrowser to see the image stored in Parse ? [activityItems addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.parse.com/apps/ClassName/collections#class/Photo/%@", self.photo.objectId]]];

Comment: What is activity items? Could you show more code of your parse object/image and how you are trying to open it in the browser?
My answer above shows how to fetch the url from parse.

Comment: [activityItems addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
            [activityItems addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.parse.com/apps/ClassName/collections#class/Photo/%@", self.photo.objectId]]];

Comment: Show how you are querying your object from Parse and the fields in your object. Also, it would be a good idea to add your code to your question above rather than here in the comments.